# Isolate the sharing of the state of an object?

Tags: f#

My code uses the following shared library

```
Module Shared
let state = new AClrClass()
let fun1 x .... = // shared function
    .... // uses state
```

Examples of using the shared library, the `state` is shared by all the functions even when multiple `main` functions (in the following code) are called in parallel.

```
Module Caller
let f1 x = Shared.fun1 x .... // other code omitted 
let f2 x = Shared.fun1 x .... // many other functions uses the function in the Shared lib
let main () = // entry point of the module. Calls f1, f2, f3...
```

Now I will need to switch to a different implementation of `Shared` which defines a class (so each calling of `Caller.main` will have its own `state`)

```
Module Shared
type Shared () =
  let state = new AClrClass()
  member __.Fun1 x .... = // shared function
    .... // uses state
```

I will need to update the `Caller` module. There may be the following approaches

1. Add another parameter of `aClrObj` to all the functions call the Shared library

   ```
   Module Caller
   let f1 o x .... = o.Fun1 x .... // other code omitted 
   let f2 o x .... = o.Fun1 x .... // many other functions uses the function in the Shared lib
   let main () = // entry point of the module. Calls f1, f2, f3... 
       let aClrObj = new AClrClass()
       f1 aClrOjb x ....
   ```
2. Define a mutable variable and set it in the `main` function.

   ```
   Module Caller
   let mutable o = new AClrClass()
   let f1 x .... = o.Fun1 x .... // other code omitted 
   let f2 x .... = o.Fun1 x .... // many other functions uses the function in the Shared lib
   let main () = // entry point of the module. Calls f1, f2, f3... 
       o <- new AClrClass()
       let aClrObj = new AClrClass()
       f1 aClrOjb x ....
   ```

Which approach is more F# idiomatic? How should the code be architectured?

Comment: If you want F# idiomatic, don't use classes. If you have to use classes, then the idiomatic ship has sailed.

Comment: But I will need to make sure each call if the library has its own Shared.state.

Comment: Well, yes. So what?

Comment: How to make sure each call of main function having it's item copy of state?

Comment: Here's a rough sketch:  Change each function except `main` to take the state object as the last parameter and return the new state.  Have `main` create a state object when you call it.  Call the other functions with their normal parameters and pipe the state object through each call.

Comment: nothing wrong with encapsulating state in classes. That's what they are for.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Are you sure that ANY use of classes in F# sail the idiomatic ship? This article gives good reasons for using classes and interfaces: https://eiriktsarpalis.wordpress.com/2017/03/20/why-oo-matters-in-f/

Answer (score 5):

*Expanding from my comment*

It's not quite clear from your code samples exactly what your module is supposed to do.  However, in general, you can pipe state through functions by having each function take the state as its last parameter, and return the new state as its value.  Then, your `main` function (or whatever function is publicly exposed) can initialize the state and pipe it through whatever functions it calls to perform the work, returning the final state.

Here's a simple example:

```
type State = State of int

let add x (State state) =
    State (state + x)

let subtract x (State state) =
    State (state - x)

let multiply x (State state) =
    State (state * x)

let divide x (State state) =
    State (state / x)

let main () =
    State 0
    |> add 3
    |> multiply 4
    |> subtract 2
    |> divide 5
    // returns (State 2)
```

This uses a `State` object to thread the current state of execution through each function.  Each function takes the current state and performs its operation on it, returning the new state.  The `main` function uses the other functions to perform a specific, more complex operation, threading the current state through each function by using the pipe-forward operator.